# List does not appear in SharePoint Customization Wizard

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a workflow in Visual Studio 2013 and when trying to associate the workflow with the list - the list is not in the drop down[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - seems visual studio needs to be restarted before it will pick up any new lists.